# How to place a control at the bottom of another one?

Tags: asp.net, html-table, slideshow

In my website I have a slideshow and under it I have a table:

```
<asp:panel ID=panel1>
  slideshow
</asp:panel>
<asp:panel ID=panel2>
  table
</asp:panel>
```

When mobile is being rotated the table is being hidden by the slideshow, is there a way to place the table at the bottom of the slideshow? I mean is there a way to say for example panel2 is at the bottom of panel1?

**slideshow:**

```html
<div style="margin:0; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px  ;min-width:100%; max-width:100%; ">
<ul id="slide" style="margin:0; padding:0;min-width:100%; max-width:100%;">
<li style="margin:0; padding:0;min-width:100%; max-width:100%;">
<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" AlternateText="xx" ImageUrl="xxx" style="min-width:100%; max-width:100%; "/>
</li>
<li style="margin:0; padding:0;min-width:100%; max-width:100%;">
image2
</li>
<li style="margin:0; padding:0;min-width:100%; max-width:100%;">
image3
</li>
<li style="margin:0; padding:0;min-width:100%; max-width:100%;">
image4
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Image under slideshow**

```html
<div style="width:100%; ">
<asp:Panel runat="server" Width="100%">
<div style=" margin:0; padding:0;min-width:100%; max-width:100%; ">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="xx" ImageUrl="xxx"   />
</div>
```

then the table goes here...

the Image placed under the slideshow is being hidden by the slideshow sometimes.. with a portion of the table under it..

my css is:

```css
.myfont {
             font-size: larger;
         }

         .thetable
         {
        padding-left:10%; 
        padding-right:0;
         width:90%;
         table-layout: fixed; 

         }
         .firsttable
         {
         padding-top:0;
         margin-top:0;        
         width:33%;

         }

         .secondtable {
          padding-top:0;
           margin-top:0;         
         width:33%;
         }

         .thirdtable {
          padding-top:0;
           margin-top:0;        
         width:33%;
         }
```

table with id thetable is the initial table containing 3 tables(firsttable, secondtable, thirdtable), because I needed to place controls in 3 columns.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could see your markup and css. a responsive design should accomodate the orientation change without requesting the page again.

Comment: I know but the problem is that I need to place the table under this slideshow and it should stay there how can I fix it under the slideshow no matter what happened? and without knowing the height of the slideshow? I mean is there a way to say control of ID1 for example is under control of ID2?

Comment: @user2849412 as said by dlatikay, add some html markup and css and someone will for sure be able to help you.

Comment: isolate your problem, make a jsfiddle, give us something to work with. "under" is representable in html/css by DOM position and z-order, below is again something else, are you using divisions or tables, which version of asp.net, vanilla controls or some library...?

Comment: any help please? when rotated the height of the images is getting bigger and the table is being hidden by it although it should move and be placed at the bottom of the slideshow but that's not working unless the page is refreshed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my slideshow when I was sliding images in it and I was adding min-width=100% and max-width=100% because I needed the image to be full-width the slideshow code didn't contain the overflow=hidden or overflow=scroll option so the image was getting too big in landscape mode and it was overlapping the next div.
Once I replaced the slideshow with this one:
http://responsiveslides.com/

everything became perfect because this slideshow is responsive and perfect!!!!